# Block/Restrict iFrame in Cordova

Tags: html, cordova, iframe

Is it possible to block or restrict iframe in Cordova? I've tried using the X-Frame-Options both on the front end and back end and it seems to work with browsers, but not with an app that is built with Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="urls you navigate or urls which you want to load inside the frame" />
```

this is called white listing , If you you are not white listing it will not load.